# image base64 string issue rest API client on chrome

Tags: php, rest, base64

I am using the chrome REST API client through I am trying to upload the image using base64 image string. So I passed the base64 image encoded string to the file & written the below code to create the image file.

```
$userAvatarData = base64_decode($signatureimage);
$userAvatarIM   = imagecreatefromstring($userAvatarData);
```

but there is difference in the get the string(using POST paramter in PHP) from passed base64 image encoded string to the file & that is why it does not create the file.

If I passed base64 image encoded string in code file instead of passing from rest API client then this will create the image.

Below is the image base64 encoded image string

```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```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a problem with Base64 encoding containing new lines. Some refer to this as "non-strict" encoding.
Your PHP code expects the file **not** to contain a new line `\n` character but it does.
You have multiple solutions here:

1. Encode without the new line character `\n`
2. Remove the new line character on the client before sending to the server
3. Remove the new lines **before** decoding the file on the server

I would also recommend passing `true` as the second parameter of `base64_decode` to throw an exception is the data contains characters outside the Base64 alphabet. 
Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php